# Mysql - Return max value from joined table

Tags: mysql

I m not sure how to return the highest value from the joined table. There are currently 4 items in the table but the query is only returning one. The MAX(b.bid) is breaking the query.

```
SELECT i.id, 
 i.user_id, 
 i.item_title, 
 i.item_description, 
 i.item_condition, 
 i.active, 
 i.add_date, 
 MAX(b.bid)
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN bids b
 ON i.id = b.item_id
WHERE i.user_id = ? AND i.active = 1 
ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

Comment: you want the max per what? per item?

Comment: You need `\group by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `max(bid)` per item, you're going to need to `group` your query by item.

```
SELECT i.id, 
 i.user_id, 
 i.item_title, 
 i.item_description, 
 i.item_condition, 
 i.active, 
 i.add_date, 
 MAX(b.bid)
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN bids b
 ON i.id = b.item_id
WHERE i.user_id = ? AND i.active = 1 
GROUP BY i.id
ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

This result depends on all the other fields being the same for each bid, which it looks like it should be. This is a valid use of the mysql extension to `group by`. Otherwise you'd need to specify each field in the select in the `group by` clause.

Comment: @ciprian good to hear. you could mark this, or any of the other similar answers as accepted if you're happy with them

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT i.id, 
 i.user_id, 
 i.item_title, 
 i.item_description, 
 i.item_condition, 
 i.active, 
 i.add_date, 
 b.bid
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(bid) AS bid, item_id 
           FROM bids 
           GROUP BY item_id) b
 ON i.id = b.item_id
WHERE i.user_id = ? AND i.active = 1 
ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

You get the max value of `bid` per `item_id` and *then* perform `LEFT JOIN` operation.

Answer (score 0):

If i am right in understanding your question, you need a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT i.id, 
 i.user_id, 
 i.item_title, 
 i.item_description, 
 i.item_condition, 
 i.active, 
 i.add_date, 
 MAX(b.bid)
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN bids b
 ON i.id = b.item_id
WHERE i.user_id = ? AND i.active = 1 
group by i.id, 
 i.user_id, 
 i.item_title, 
 i.item_description, 
 i.item_condition, 
 i.active, 
 i.add_date
ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

Comment: @Arion in this instance, this is almost certainly the same as grouping by just i.id. if it provides a different result, then this is in fact _necessary_ to get accurate results. and your statement about the treatment of the fields not present in the group by, or aggregate, but present in the select is not accurate. mysql populates these fields with _indeterminate_ values, it does not add them to the group by.  the only way to ensure you get the values you expect, is if there is only one possible value in the group - or you use an aggregate function. [see this](http://tinyurl.com/psr855c)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT i.id, 
 i.user_id, 
 i.item_title, 
 i.item_description, 
 i.item_condition, 
 i.active, 
 i.add_date, 
 b.bid
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        MAX(bids.bid) as bid,
        bids.item_id
    FROM
        bids
    GROUP BY
        bids.item_id
) as b
 ON i.id = b.item_id
WHERE i.user_id = ? AND i.active = 1 
ORDER BY i.id DESC
```